# Installing Django in PyCharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Do I really need to install Django in PyCharm every time I'm going to run a project? I mean I already did it yesterday and today when I run in the terminal the `python manage.py runserver`  it said that:

```
"ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your
PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?"
```

Is there a way to install it just once so I can just run my project or is that how it really works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this ..

```
pip install django
```

If it doesn't work you can install django manually in Pycharm..
Go  to **File** > **Settings** > **Project** > **Python Interpreter** > Now pycharm will show you the list of modules  install the module which you want..

Comment: Thanks! Now that I installed django manually and close and reopen the pycharm, I'll just type "python manage.py runserver" in the terminal and it will not display the 

"ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?"

message. Right?

Comment: @KimpoyLoto when you install your django through terminal which message show? because if you install any module manually through pycharm .. it doesn't for your whole environment variables it is only for your pycharm.. and if you wanna work through virtualenv visit this. [blog]: https://www.javatpoint.com/django-virtual-environment-setup " Django Virtual Environment Setups"

Comment: It showed the ImportError: message. Actually I'm only using pycharm and what you suggested worked. So, to use django for my whole environment variables, I need to follow the steps in the link that you give, right? Thanks a lot! I appreciate your help!